# text in Edittext do not appears proper

Tags: android

I am having a customized `EditText` in a layout . The text in that are properly arranged as You can see in the image.Even if  the `EditText` is not customized then also the same problem. Some time the letter appears one above the other.

First 3 letters are neatly arranged that is : 
1.Harry Potter
2.n
3.m:'(
And the rest are not neatly arranged.Please help me in this case

[text in Edittext do not appears proper-IMAGE](http://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/11068621195/)

```
<com.android.project.birthdayreminder.LineEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtextview_note"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"       
                    android:hint="Notes:\nThings planned for the Birthday /Aniversary"       
                    android:singleLine="false" 
                    android:textColor="#000000"                
                    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                    android:gravity="top"                                       
                    android:background="@drawable/activity_background"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip"/>
```

Comment: My guess would be that it's the drawing code for the lines which is off. You should try with an unmodified View, screenshot and measure the pixels, if using the same char all over the view. This is done to narrow down on the error. Then, stepwise code and check what works...

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is actually dangerous, since you are trying to fit some text lines into a background.

You don't know in advance what device is going to run your application, so despite it looks alright in your device other devices could scale the background in a different way or have a different font size.

I could try to help you make that text fit between the lines, but I think that's not a suitable solution. Instead, I would remove the lines from the background or try to draw the lines as a placeholder once you know the line height, but not sooner.

Hope this helps.